# Struts 2 jquery pagination

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, pagination

I want to implement pagination in my page.I am using struts 2 and hibernate.I have implemented a small jqyery pagination but I want to retrieve data from database.I have searched but i can't find something that matches to my code.I want to implement pagination with jquery for client side.Thanks!

index.jsp

```
<div id="divs">
    <s:if test="listData.size() > 0">
        <s:iterator value="listData" status="status">

            <article <s:if test="#status.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>>
           <div>
            <header >

                <h2 class="data-title">
                    <s:url id="idUrl" action="data/viewRead"><s:param name="id"><s:property value="id" /></s:param></s:url>
                    <s:a href="%{idUrl}" style="color: #3071A9"><s:property value="title" /></s:a>
                </h2>
                <span class="data-user"><s:property value="user.accountName" /></span> | <span class="data-created"><s:property value="created" /></span>

            </header>

        <p class="read"><s:property value="description" /></p>

            </div>
            </article>

         </s:iterator>
    </s:if>

</div>
```

dataAction.java

```
public String listThrowException() {

          setListThrowException(facade.listData());

}
```

dataActionImpl.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Data> listData() {
        List<Data> list;
        Query query;
        try {

            query = em.createQuery("from Data order by id desc");
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(30);
            list = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }finally{

        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @AleksandrM ,how to implement pagination based in my code,any link that can help me,i have seen tutorial but those offer with jtable,i do not want to implement with jtable,i want to implement only pagination.Thanks!

Comment: Those are two types of issues.  One is making sure you expose the total number of items,  the index and page size.  That part should be from struts.  The second is using a pagination library (or build it yourself) to do the calculations and displaying the links for the different pages.

Comment: @Ruggs,can you guide me with simple tutorials?I can make from server side but i am not good in jquery!If you give any link,but not using jTable Library,i do not use table!I want to send a request with ajax and take back the result from server!The idea is implementing pagination for a lot of data,server side pagination.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.datatables.net/ - I use this all the time, provided that the total list size is not too big

Comment: I have seen this before but i want pagination when total list size is too big and i don't want table option,i just want to list without table.Thanks for reply! I am working on this for the moment  http://prathap-puppala.blogspot.com/2011/06/struts-2-pagination-example.html